# what exactly mean AWS region and choosing right region for business

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-regions

What exactly is the **region** in **AWS** world?

I have to ask **which region** is the right region for my business.Which factors are important before selecting region in AWS?

Answer (score 5):

An **AWS Region** is a physical cluster of data centers located in a specific geographic location.

So, the **Sydney Region** data centers are all located in Sydney and the **Oregon Region** has data centers all located in Oregon.

A region consists of multiple **Availability Zones**. An Availability Zone is one or more data centers that contain the physical infrastructure that provides AWS services (eg data, storage, networking). There are very high-speed connections between Availability Zones within a Region.

So, which Region to choose? It should typically be the one **closest to your customers** (to provide faster response) or perhaps **closest to your existing data center** if you are connecting it to AWS.

You might want to use **multiple data centers** so that you have services closest to customers spread around the world, rather than having them all connect back to one location. Or, you might want to use multiple Regions for **redundancy in case of failure**. ([Project Nimble: Region Evacuation Reimagined – Netflix TechBlog](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/project-nimble-region-evacuation-reimagined-d0d0568254d4))

There might also be **legal requirements** of which Region to use (based on data governance, privacy laws, etc). You might even choose a Region based on a **lower price** (USA regions are generally lower cost than others, especially for Internet data transfer costs).

You might also choose a region based upon **which services are available**: [Region Table](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/?p=gi)

See also: [Global Cloud Infrastructure | Regions & Availability Zones | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/)

Comment: Great summary! One thing I'd like to add is that many other things are important to choose your AWS Region besides the distance to your customers. See this excellent blog post about that topic. [Save yourself a lot of pain (and money) by choosing your AWS Region wisely](https://www.concurrencylabs.com/blog/choose-your-aws-region-wisely/)

Answer (score 3):

The definition and documentation of AWS Region is stated in the above comments. In summary, AWS Region is a separate geographic area. AWS Region has Availability Zones which are isolated data centers. Availability Zones is used for high availability. There are 2 or more Availability Zones for each region.

Which factors are important before selecting region in AWS?

There are several factors to consider.

1. **Latency** - The faster your data center, the better your performance. This link can display the latency between ec2 instances. https://www.cloudping.co/
2. **Cost** - Different region has different cost. So far, North Virginia is the cheapest.
3. **AWS Services to use** - Not all AWS Services are available in all regions. This link can display the supported services per region. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of resources that can help you understand AWS regions, availability zones, and how to architect using them, including:

- AWS: [Regions and Availability Zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html)
- AWS: [Architecting for the Cloud: Best Practices](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/architecting-for-the-aws-cloud-best-practices/)
- CloudAcademy: [How to Pick the Best AWS Region for Your Workload](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-choose-the-best-aws-region-for-your-workload/)